# Problema usin fancybox with new images added through jQuery Append

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm adding new images to the DOM to this DIV...

```
<div id="photoArea"></div>
```

And I load the new images like this...

```
function showImages(token,status){
var jqxhr = $.getJSON("/api/1/photos/show.json/?callback=?",{ 
    token: token,
    status_id: status,
},function(data) {
    var html = "";
$.each(data.photos, function(i,photo){
    html = '<a class="fancybox" rel="gallery1" href="/photos/'+photo.owner_id+'/'+photo.id+'-'+photo.photo_token+'.'+photo.extension+'">';
    html += '<img src="/photos/'+photo.owner_id+'/'+photo.id+'-'+photo.photo_token+'x200.'+photo.extension+'" alt="" /> ';
    html += '</a>';
    $('#photoArea').append(html);
});
}).success(function(data) { });
} // end function
```

I try a lot of combinations. One of them is:

```
$(document).on("click",".fancybox",function(ev){
 $.fancybox({
    href: this,
    type: 'image'
 });
});
```

When I clic over the images, only is showed the image in the navigator.

I'm using jQuery 1.7 and fancybox v2. Las Chrome and Firefox versions

Any idea of how to show the new images in fancybox to this new images I

Answer (score 0):

the "on" function is generally used on existing items of your DOM.
If you want to account for items retreived through ajax, it's better to use .delegate(). something like

```
$("#photoArea").delegate("img.fancybox", "click", function() {
    ...
});
```

Also what's the point of having an empty success function if you're already implementing it in inside the getJSON function ? You should probably just remove that and verify with Firebug or Chrome Inspector that your data is being in fact added to the DOM.

Hope that help :)

Comment: _the "on" function is generally used on existing items of your DOM_ - That is not necessarily true because `.on()` has actually replaced `.live()` since jQuery v1.7.x. For older versions `.delegate()` is recommended instead of `.live()` though.

Answer (score 0):

With fancybox v2.x you just need this custom script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  // options if needed
 }); // fancybox
}); // ready
```

fancybox v2.x supports both existing and dynamically added elements so you don't need either `.on()` or `.delegate()`. Just make sure that jQuery, then fancybox js file and your custom script are loaded before the container where you add your images.